# No puedo entrar a una ruta de archivo

Tags: php, html, html5

Intento acceder a **procesamientos.php** a través de un enlace que se envia de esta manera: Primero lo envia mediante un formulario:

```
<form id="regiration_form" action=?menu=formulaio_registrar_datos" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

El cual lo recoge un archivo routing.php, que va ha ser el encargado de abrir el archivo procesamientos.php

```
if ($_GET['menu']=='formulaio_registrar_datos') {
   require_once('procesamientos.php');
}
```

Sino que me da como esto la ruta:

> http_//0.0.0.0:8080/?nombre=Queso&ciudad=Va&calle=Quien&numero=222&correo=&telefono=6321&logotipo=IMG_20210107_000659.jpg

Cuando la ruta que necesito es esta:

> http_//0.0.0.0:8080/?menu=formulaio_registrar_datos

Comment: primero el `action` le falta una comilla y segundo el metodo que utilizas para enviar el formulario es `get` cuando deberia ser `post`.

Comment: Debe ser get ya que lo pasa como para en la url @Bryro

Comment: Prueba a poner el `action` correctamente.

Comment: @DanielJiménez en tu pregunta pones especicamente que solo se pasa por get el `menu=formulaio_registrar_datos` pero bueno.... solo tienes entonces el action mal.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algunos errores:

1. En formularios por método GET no puedes agregar parámetros, tienen que ir necesariamente como campos, aunque sean ocultos.
2. No es precisamente error, pero sí es recomendable que en el atributo *action* especifiques la página que va a procesar el formulario.
3. El atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` se utiliza solo para enviar archivos y no aplica con método GET. Si quieres enviar archivos debes [cambiar a método POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#un_caso_especial_el_env%C3%ADo_de_archivos).

```
<form id="regiration_form" action="procesamientos.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="menu" value="formulario_registrar_datos">
... Aquí el resto de campos y botón "submit" ...
</form>
```

Al enviar el formulario, la acción se complementará y, de ser necesario, se [cambiarán algunos caracteres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_porciento) para poder ser enviados correctamente por URL, que es como funciona el método GET. Ejemplo de ruta al procesar:

```
procesamientos.php?menu=formulario_registrar_datos&otro_campo_oculto_o_visible=valor%20del%20campo%20con%20espacios
```

Al procesar por POST puedes enviar también datos por $_GET:

```
<form id="regiration_form" action="procesamientos.php?menu=formulario_registrar_datos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
... Aquí el resto de campos y botón "submit" ...
</form>
```

En PHP recibes los datos:

```
// Datos recibidos por URL
$menu = $_GET['menu'];
// Datos recibidos por formulario
$otroCampo = $_POST['otro_campo'];
// Archivos
$archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
```

Comment: Ya le puse asi:`<form id="regiration_form" action="procesamientos.php?menu=formulaio_registrar_datos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`  y en donde recibe los datos `if ($_POST['menu']=='formulario_registrar_datos) {
  require_once('procesamientos.php');
 } `pero me sigue sin abrir el archivo

Comment: `menu` lo recibes en `$_GET['menu']` porque es parte de la URL, no importa que el formulario se procese por POST.